# Normalization properties

Tags: database-normalization

what are the properties of Normalization related to Database?

Is there any relation between ACID properties and Normalization properties?

Comment: Wikipedia could give you these answers much faster, and more completely than you are likely to get on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Normalization and ACID are different things.

*ACID* refers to four important properties of transactions. Each transaction is

- Atomic (all or nothing),
- Consistent (changing the database
  from one consistent state to
  another),
- Isolated (hidden from other
  transactions until it's committed),
- Durable (after `COMMIT`, data
  survives a crash)

*Normalization* refers to the process of refining the structure of a relation (informally, a table) by identifying dependencies that lead to trouble, and then decomposing a table into two or more tables that have more favorable properties.

During normalization, the statements that create and alter tables are themselves database transactions. The ACID properties apply to those statements, as well as the more common `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` statements.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no relation between ACID and Normalization properties.

check basic of normalization : http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm